# Distributed Program Execution Manager

Tags: java, distributed, execution

Given the information about machines in a cluster (IP address/machine name) and a program (Java language) to run, is there a software (manager) available which would execute this program and returns the output along with the runtimes on each of the machines?

Currently, I am using a shell script to do this, but I couldn't get time taken (in secs) to run the java program back. It would be good if there is some distributed program execution manager like the one I described above.

Comment: what do you mean "the runtimes?"

Comment: by runtime I meant the time taken (in secs) to run the java program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing your own script, you could simply use something like [tentakel](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/execute-commands-on-multiple-linux-or-unix-servers-part-ii.html) or [shmux](http://web.taranis.org/shmux/) to run your application parallel on multiple nodes . You can run tentakel as

```
tentakel 'time <your application name>'
```

to get the output and the time it takes for the application to run.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions :). These look like exactly what I need. I will check them out. However, the development on both these tools seem to have long been stopped. But I guess, here, it is not much of a concern.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) for stuff like that. It was originally written for performing software builds and tests, but is more generic than that. Basically a controller for managing jobs and executions along with a client to deploy on nodes. [Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/) is another option if you have flexibility to re-write your app for a specific distributed computing framework.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I had Hadoop in mind, sorry I didn't mention that. I want a functionality which is like the job controller in Hadoop. Similar to the manner in which it would run map & reduce on all the nodes, I want my manager to run my java program on all the nodes and collect the output.

Comment: Hudson will let you do that without any changes to your program. It can invoke an arbitrary command on the host that it has a slave installed, the result (command output and files you specify) are sent back to the controller machine, where they can be reviewed as necessary. You can setup jobs to trigger depending on results of other jobs, create matrixes of permutations to execute, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question very much. What "runtime" do you want to get back? What clustering solution are you using? For distributed communication in Java I would recommend JGroups. FOr distributed JVM check Terracotta.

Comment: I want to get the time it takes to run the program and also I want to get the output of the program for each machine in the cluster on which the program is run. What does it mean by a clustering solution?